# Running into problems installing MongoDB on MacOS Terminal

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mern

I am trying to install mongoDB as a macOS service but I am running to some errors

1. I first put in the terminal

   `brew tap mongodb`

Nothing really happens.

2. But, when I run:

`brew install mongodb-community@5.0`

I receive:

`Warning: No available formula with the name "mongosh" (dependency of mongodb/brew/mongodb-community). Did you mean mongocli?`

`==> Searching for similarly named fo This similarly named formula was found: mongocli ✔`

`To install it, run: brew install mongocli ✔ It was migrated from mongodb/brew to homebrew/core.`

3. Finally, when I run

`brew services start mongodb-community@5.0`

I receive

`Error: Formula 'mongodb-community' is not installed.`

Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same happen, however my issue was actually with this error:

> fatal: could not solve HEAD to a revision

solve it using:

```
git -C $(brew --repository homebrew/core) checkout master
```

you can also:

```
brew update

brew upgrade

brew upgrade --cask

brew cleanup
```

and then restart the mongodb community edition install process again! Worked for me!

Comment: You just saved my laptop, I was about to throw it off of the balcony.... This was on a FRESH install of homebrew, and it doesnt work out of the box, and no notes on their website about this potential issue [Jackie Chan wtf face]

Comment: Glad this helped!

Answer (score 3):

I was also having the same issue. This solved it for me:

```
git -C $(brew --repository homebrew/core) checkout master

brew update

brew upgrade

brew upgrade --cask

brew cleanup
```

Then install the latest version of Mongodb community using:

```
brew install mongodb-community@6.0
```

Note: version might be outdated at the time you're reading this

Answer (score 2):

I am experiencing the exact same problem (I am using MacOC version 11.5.1).

The reason why your `brew tap mongodb` does not seem to be doing anything may be because you have already tapped into mongodb. Try untapping with `brew untap mongodb`and retapping with `brew tap mongodb/brew`.

After you have established the connection, try installing again with `brew install mongodb-community@5.0`. At this stage, I could not get the installation to work for version 5.0 so I installed version 4.4 instead (with `brew install mongodb-community@4.4`).

After that, try running mongo with `brew services start mongodb-community@5.0` (or `brew services start mongodb-community@4.4` if you have installed 4.4 version) and it should work just fine!

If you have installed version 4.4, be sure to run the command `PATH="/usr/local/opt/mongodb-community@4.4/bin" mongo` to start the mongo shell.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check with `brew list | grep mongo` that mongodb-community, mongodb-database-tools, mongosh exist at your PC. If they do not exist, install them with brew.
2. Recently also installed mongodb V4.4.5 and can not start it with `brew services start mongodb-community`. For me works starting it manually as a background process as admin `sudo mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf --fork`
3. And last call `mongo` to work with mongoDB shell.

Reason: directory/file access issue. Not sure.